# LINQ equivalent to Seq.scan

Tags: c#, linq, f#, ienumerable

Does C# have a LINQ equivalent to F#'s [`Seq.scan`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#scan)--like `fold` but storing the aggregated value at every step? (One like `reduce` that doesn't require a starting state would work at least as well.)

If one does not exist, I can work around its absence by writing my own or using LanguageExt's method, but I prefer to use core libraries when possible.

Comment: You mean like the Aggregate method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-aggregate-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-0-0)))

Comment: @DavidL No, that returns only one value. I want one that returns each `TAccumulate` it calculates.

Comment: LanguageExt gives me what I want, so this isn't urgent anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not have a direct LINQ equivalent to F#'s `Seq.scan` method.

You can mimic this functionality with the LINQ Aggregator method by passing a collection as the seed value and performing lookups on the previous accumulations:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<Data> 
{ 
    new Data { Count = 1 }, 
    new Data { Count = 2 }, 
    new Data { Count = 1 }, 
    new Data { Count = 5 }, 
    new Data { Count = 3 } 
};

var accumulatedValues = data.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (current, nextValue) =>
{
    var lastValue = current.Count > 0 ? current[current.Count - 1] : 0;
    var updatedValue = lastValue + nextValue.Count;
    current.Add(updatedValue);
    return current;
});
```

---

In addition, it is relatively trivial to create your own extension method that mimics the `Aggregate` function, but returns a list of all accumulation steps instead of a single value.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> Accumulate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        TAccumulate seed, 
        Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator)
    {
        var accumulation = new List<TAccumulate>();

        var current = seed;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            current = accumulator(current, item);
            accumulation.Add(current);
        }

        return accumulation;
    }
}
```

This works well for both collections of primitive values as well as collections of objects:

```
var firstAccumulation = 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Accumulate(0, (acc, newValue) => acc + newValue);
```

or

```
public class Data
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<Data> 
{ 
    new Data { Count = 1 }, 
    new Data { Count = 2 }, 
    new Data { Count = 1 }, 
    new Data { Count = 5 }, 
    new Data { Count = 3 } 
};

var secondAccumulation = data.Accumulate(0, (acc, newValue) => acc + newValue.Count);
```

Comment: I know it's easy. I just want to avoid adding to my library unless I need to do so.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question @LyndonGingerich. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I should have clarified further. All I want to know is whether Linq has a built-in equivalent to `Seq.scan`. You seem to be implying that it doesn't. If you'll state so explicitly, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @LyndonGingerich correct, there is no directly equivalent method. I've updated my answer to explicitly state so.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. In [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) from Reactive Extentions there's the [Scan](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Scan.cs#L23) operator which

> Generates a sequence of accumulated values by scanning the source sequence and applying an accumulator function.